# ServiceBus : Asynchronous MessageSender.BeginSend() , Should I put Thread.Sleep()

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azureservicebus

Working Code here

```
static MessageSender TopicClient;
public static void SendTopicMessage(BrokeredMessage message)
{
 IAsyncResult result = TopicClient.BeginSend(message, processEndSend, TopicClient);
 Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
public static void processEndSend(IAsyncResult result)
{
  MessageSender messageSender = result.AsyncState as MessageSender;
  messageSender.EndSend(result);
}
```

The above code is working. But I don't know why should I put Thread.Sleep(). I dont want to keep Thread.Sleep(). But It's not working I remove that Thread.Sleep(). Any Suggestion?

Comment: in your code Thread.Sleep() is not at all required. What is the problem you getting if you remove the Thread.Sleep here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are calling the SendTopicMessage from a thread...

So if you remove Sleep() here your thread Terminated once its sent your first message...If you put Sleep(5000), you are sending next messages with in the 5 sec time duration so the thread kept alive.

I think You are designing Bad Architecture. Correct me If i am wrong.

For Clear understanding of your flow... Please post enough code snippets...

Comment: NavaRajan, You are right, I was testing in the console application with for loop. I dint work if I remove the thread. But moved to Webrole main application .Its working without Thread.Sleep();

Comment: @sivaL then close this question.